# update data using ajax laravel 8

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel-8

i'm trying to update data using ajax but ajax not working in Controller Function

***Error in incpect console***

PATCH http://127.0.0.1:8000/userData 500 (Internal Server Error)
send    @   jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2
ajax    @   jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2
(anonymous) @   home:438
dispatch    @   jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2
v.handle    @   jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2

**ajax script**

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

$(document).on("click", "#update_data", function() { 
    var url = "{{URL('/userData')}}";
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "PATCH",
        cache: false,
        data:{
            _token:'{{ csrf_token() }}',
            lat: $('#lat').val(),
            lon: $('#lon').val()
        },
        success: function(dataResult){
            dataResult = JSON.parse(dataResult);
         if(dataResult.statusCode)
         {
            window.location = "/userData";
         }
         else{
             alert("Internal Server Error");
         }
            
        }
    });
});
```

});

**update function in controller**

```
public function update()
{
    return redirect()->route('user.home');
    if(request('lat')){
        userData::Where('user_id',auth()->user()->id)->update( [ 'lat' => request('lat'), 'lon' => request('lon') ]);
    }
    return json_encode(array('statusCode'=>200));
}
```

***route***

Route::Patch('/userData','UserController@update');

Answer (score 0):

You're returning the redirect in the first place which it will running in the first place. You need to remove it, so the code should be :

```
public function update(Request $request)
{
    if($request->has('lat')){
        $update = userData::where('user_id',auth()->user()->id)
          ->update([ 
             'lat' => $request->lat, 
             'lon' => $request->lon 
          ]);
        if ($update) {
           return response()->json([
              'statusCode' => 200
           ]);
        }
    }
    return response()->json([
        'statusCode' => 500 //for internal server error
    ])
}
```

Comment: i try it same problem i cant reach function controller i think problem from ajax function i try put dd('hello') in controller function nothing happen

Comment: Have you try to enable the APP_DEBUG and see the preview result in network inspect element ? Let me know what the error is and if you don't mind can you share the route for this update controller ?